# Is there a vay to make this code faster? Drawing a point on chart is slow

Tags: vb.net, performance, charts, vb.net-2010

is there any way to make this work faster?

Here is my sample code in vb.net. This adds a point on a chart at mouse position but it is quite slow.

```
    Private Sub Chart2_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart2.MouseMove
    Dim coord() As Double = GetAxisValuesFromMouse(e.X, e.Y)

    Dim test As Series
    Try
        Chart2.Series.RemoveAt(1)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Dim pt As New DataPoint
    pt.XValue = coord(0)
    pt.YValues(0) = coord(1)

    test = New Series
    Chart2.Series.Add(test)
    Chart2.Series(test.Name).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
    Chart2.Series(test.Name).Points.Add(pt)

End Sub
```

Function returns the coordinates of x and y axis at mouse position.

```
Private Function GetAxisValuesFromMouse(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Double()
    Dim coord(1) As Double
    Dim chartArea = Chart2.ChartAreas(0)
    coord(0) = chartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(x)
    coord(1) = chartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(y)
    Return coord
End Function
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How many datapoints are in the first graph?  Use less.

Comment: Thousands, but i can't modify that. I am not modifying that series in any way, does number of point in that series really matter?

Comment: It looks like it's painting the entire thing on every mouse move event.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, should be on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Didn't know about that page. Thank you, will ask there.

Comment: @Mike, you are correct, everything is redrawn every time i add a series with a point. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Chart2` window, there's got to be a way to perform an `Invalidate` with a clipping rectangle.

Another method I use is not to paint directly to the window, but instead paint to a memory bitmap, which I then BLT to the visible window. That can actually be faster because in painting to the bitmap it's not having to slow down to do clipping. This also gives a (fake) impression of speed because I can't see the green lines being redrawn (even though they are).

Yet another method is, when painting the dot where the mouse is, XOR it to the screen.
Then when I move it, XOR it in the old location (to erase it), and then XOR it in the new location. That way, I'm not repainting all those little green lines that haven't moved.

Still another method is: if there are thousands of little lines in the graph, some of them have to be of length zero pixels. They take time to draw even though they contribute nothing to the image, so they could be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to figure something out but i am not a programmer so it's maybe hard form me to grasp all of these concepts.

Comment: I managed to speed it up a bit with turning off anti-aliasing and using fastline type for my series instead of line type.

Comment: @micco: That sounds like a good start. To go further, you might have to code "closer to the metal", i.e. I know VB lets you work at the level of the Win32 API.

Answer (score -1):

Use **Flexcell Grid control**
it is superb control it provide all those feature which provide by datagrid control and more 
FlexCell is a flexible and easy to use grid control. ... It provides comprehensive functions such as Print, Print Preview, Chart, ... Using FlexCell Grid Control, you can create the professional user interfaces and report form in your application. ... your applications coded in Visual Basic, Visual FoxPro, Visual C++, VB.net, C#, etc.